# Count the number of processes and kill them

Tags: bash, sh

I am writing a script to kill all instances of the same process. As it is going to be used on Linux, AIX, HP-UX and Solaris, I need to use only built-in bash (sh) functions. That's why `killall`, `pkill`, etc. don't work for me.

Once there is only one instance of a process it should be just killed in traditional way:

```
kill -TERM `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $process | awk '{print $2}'`
```

However sometimes the program has extra instances running and that's why `ps -ef | …` returns more than one PID. That needs to be reported.

example:

```
bash-3.2$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep perl | awk '{print $2}'
5267  
5268  
5269  
5270  
5271
```

My thought was to store those values in a temporary variable and then send kill signal to each in a for loop.

```
bash-3.2$ tmp=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep perl | awk '{print $2}'`  
bash-3.2$ echo $tmp  
5267 5268 5269 5270 5271
```

However I still need the information if such a case occurred (how many instances were present).
It seems I need to check the whole string stored in the `tmp` variable and maybe count spaces?

Anyway the questions reduces to how to check how many values the `$tmp` variable stores?

Comment: You could just use a counter in your loop to tell you homw many procs were killed.

Comment: @glennjackman [Yes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/ps.html) (but marked XSI in current POSIX+OpenGroup specs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For maximum [portability](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html) and reliability, use `-A` (POSIX synonym of `-e`) and a custom format with `-o` rather than `-f`.

Your filtering of the output of `ps` is brittle: it may match other processes. You've had to exclude the grep process, and you may need to exclude your script as well, and there may be other completely innocent processes caught in the fray (such as your script itself) because their command line happens to contain `$process` as a substring. Make your filtering as strict as possible. With `ps -o pid= -o comm=`, you get just two columns (PID and command without arguments) with no header.

You don't need to use a loop to do the killing, `kill` accepts multiple arguments. For the counting, let the shell do it: you have a whitespace-separated list of numbers, to let the shell do the word splitting (with `$(…)` outside quotes) and count the number of resulting words (`$#`).

```
count_and_kill_processes () {
  set -- $(ps -A -o pid= -o comm= |
           awk -v "name=$process" '$2 == name {print $1}')
  count=$#
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then kill "$@"; fi
}
count_and_kill_processes foo
# now the number of killed processes is in $count
```

If your shell is bash or ksh on all machines, you can use an array.

```
pids=($(ps -A -o pid= -o comm= |
           awk -v "name=$process" '$2 == name {print $1}') )
if [[ $# -ne 0 ]]; then kill "$@"; fi
# the number of killed processes is ${#pids}
```

Answer (score 2):

use xargs:

```
ps aux | grep -ie perl | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop which should work in both cases:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $process | awk '{print $2}'); do
  echo $pid
done
```

Or count the number of matches:

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $process | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l) -gt 1 ]
then
  # more than one
fi
```